# Cookie manager is not deleting the cookies or expire them

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I'm utilizing the `android.webkit.CookieManager` for managing cookies within my `WebView`. My process involves initially clearing out old cookies by setting their `Max-Age=0`, followed by introducing new cookies. The context of this operation is transitioning from a native screen to a `WebView`, during which I aim to ensure that any existing sessionId is replaced with my own, maintaining consistency across the navigation from the native screen to the `WebView`. Despite my efforts, I end up with two cookies bearing the same name but different values. How can I effectively delete or replace a specific cookie by its name?

```
class CookieProviderImpl(
    private val cookieManager: CookieManager,
    private val analyticsEventLogger: AnalyticsEventLogger,
) : CookieProvider {

    override suspend fun injectCookies() {
        val baseUrl = "www.baseURL.com"
        val currentCookies = cookieManager.getCookie(baseUrl)?.split("; ")?.associate {
            val (name, value) = it.split("=")
            name to value
        } ?: mapOf()

        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)

        val cookiesToSet = mapOf(
            CookiesNames.DEVICE_ID to analyticsEventLogger.getVisitorId(),
            CookiesNames.SESSION_ID to analyticsEventLogger.getSessionId(),
            CookiesNames.SESSION_TIMESTAMP to System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        )

        currentCookies.forEach { (name, _) ->
            if (cookiesToSet.keys.contains(name)) {
                cookieManager.setCookie(baseUrl, "$name=''; Max-Age=0")
            }
        }

        cookieManager.flush()
        cookiesToSet.forEach { (name, value) ->
            cookieManager.setCookie(baseUrl, "$name=$value")
        }

        cookieManager.flush()
    }

    override fun removeAllCookies() {
        cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null)
    }
}
```

The architecture is `CookieProvider` is injected in `ViewModel`, where `VM` is injected in `composable` function where I am using `AndroidView` function to load the page

I inject the cookies in two places, first on initialization

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        viewModel.injectCookies()
    }
})
```

And after that every time before loading new URL

```
AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                        onCanGoBackChange(view?.canGoBack() ?: false)
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                    }

                    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                        runBlocking { injectCookies() }
                        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
                    }
                }
              
            }
        },
        update = { webview ->
            onWebViewUpdate(webview)
            webview.loadUrl(url)
        }
    )
```